# Can you have relative numbers, but for characters/words in a line?

Tags: vimrc, neovim, plugin

This is `relativenumber`. It shows the line numbers, relative to your cursor:

```
1 one line before your cursor
0 your cursor is here
1 first line after
2 second line
3 third line
4 and so on
```

It's super useful for quickly editing a number of lines. But is it possible to have the same thing, except for characters in a line? Something like this:

```
8    3  0 2      10   16    22 25  X  X        X  X     X      X       X       X      X
This is a pretty long line. It can be annoying to edit. EspeciallyIfThere'sALotOfTextAtOnce
        ^
 your cursor is here
```

You can see that each word or longer string of characters has a relative character count number on top of it (I stopped using numbers and started using X's eventually, but you get the point).

So let's say I want to edit the string `It can be annoying` to `It is annoying`. I could do `25k` to go to the word I want to edit, type `2cw` to change two words and replace them with the string "is".

Considerations:

- The numbers need to be spaced out because having them too close to each other would be confusing
- Using characters instead of numbers (e.g X and Y instead of 100 and 105) might be a good idea

Is there any existing solution out there for accomplishing this? I'd like to give it a try.

---

Edit: An even better idea might be to display word numbers instead of character numbers. Like this:

```
2    1  0 1      2    3     4  5   6  7        8  9          
This is a pretty long line. It can be annoying to edit. 
        ^
 your cursor is here
```

If the number `5` is on top of the "can", then I can just type `5w` to go to the word "can".

Comment: I've never seen anything that numbers columns but there are a number of plugins that make it easy to navigate to various places on a line (or page) using "hints" (e.g. 1-3 letter tags). [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) is probably the most popular of these.

Comment: BTW, in native Vim you could just do `fc` to get to `can`. Or `2fl` to get to `line`. And so on. Combined with `;` and `,` to go forward/backward by one occurrence and you can move about pretty adeptly.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware, but that's not reliable. If there's a "c" character somewhere in between there, then you will go to the first "c" you encounter, not the one you want to go to. Though, I didn't know about `;` and `,`, so maybe I should give it another shot (though I would still prefer being able to get to where I want to go with one command, and not have to pay attention to whether I've gone too far or not).  I've been typing `/can`, but I'm looking for something faster, where I don't have to worry about escaping regex

Comment: I have never seen something like this. It might be possible to script something and (ab-use) the tabline for that

Comment: Yeah, I'd never use `/can` but I use `f`, `F`, `t`, `T`, `;`, `,` (along with the other basics like `w` and `b`) pretty adroitly after some practice...to the point that I don't feel the need for something like what you describe or EasyMotion.

Comment: Check out the [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) plug-in.

Comment: Personally I’ve come to believe that searching for target fragments is the fastest way to get places.

Comment: Another alternative is [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak/blob/master/doc/sneak.txt). But for this I'd rather `/` my way to where I need, or use `f`, maybe `f.ww`. This is pretty straightforward, at least once you're comfortable with that and don't even think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Plugin suggestions from the comments:

- [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion)
- [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak/blob/master/doc/sneak.txt)